# Determine number of responses in JSON response

Tags: javascript, html, json, api, rest

Thank you for the help in advance. I'd like to know how in javascript I can calculate the total number of responses in a JSON response that conform to a particular rule.

This is the JSON response i am referencing

```
[  
   {  
      "InvoiceNumber":"INV0319",
      "InvoiceOrder":9,
      "Balance":2.0000,
      "CustomerID":"9b4b615f-2815-4f9c-a765-d7f8517cea6a",
      "CustomerName":"Batman",
      "InvoiceAmount":2.0000,
      "InvoiceDate":"2015-09-17T00:00:00+00:00",
      "DueDate":null,
      "Status":2,
      "Reference":null,
      "Notes":null,
      "IsOverdue":false
   },
   ...
```

In the response there is a object called "IsOverDue": false.

Typically in this response there will be many results that have a mixture of false and true.

Lets say as a example there is 30 IsOverDue: true in a response and 20 IsOverDue: False

How would i be able to calculate that there is 30 (out of the total 50) IsOverDue: True in the response programmatically

Thanks

Comment: Show us what you've tried, and we''ll help you with it.

Comment: Use any one of a variety of array loop methods and count them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop to each obj and test their properties 'IsOverDue' to true then add to your counter for overdue...
Try reading and running my code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
//GLOBAL VARS
var overdueCount = 0;
var json = [{  
        "IsOverdue":true
     },
     {  
        "IsOverdue":false
     },
     {  
        "IsOverdue":false
     }];
function countOverDue(){
 overdueCount = 0;
 for(var x = 0; x<json.length; x++){
  if(json[x].IsOverdue){
   overdueCount++;
  }
 }
}

countOverDue();
alert("There is "+overdueCount+" over due out of "+json.length);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to count the number of overdue values, and return an integer.

```
function getOverdue(arr) {
  return arr.reduce(function(p, c) {
    return c.IsOverdue ? ++p : p;
  }, 0);
}

getOverdue(arr); // 3
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/vLg4q70p/1/)

Answer (score 0):

The JSON response is just an array like we have here:

```
var jsonArray = [
    {
      name: 'James',
      isTrue: true
    },
    {
      name: 'Vicky',
      isTrue: true
    },{
      name: 'Ryan',
      isTrue: true
    },
  {
    name: 'Tim',
    isTrue: false
  }
];
var areLate = [];
```

So really we are just asking 'how do I go through an array and pick out the items I want'. Which I like to do like:

```
jsonArray.forEach( function (element) { 
    if(!element.isTrue){
      areLate.push(element);
    }
});
```

as in `array.forEach(callback(element))`. I am `pushing` (adding to a new array I defined right below the `jsonArray`) if the `element`'s property `isTrue` returns `false`. We show that our worker did the job correctly by `console.log`.

```
console.log(areLate);
```

If you want to find out how many are false, we can `console.log(areLate.length)` but now we have all of the information in a new array that we can use for later (like finding the length).

Comment: Answers with code only and no description or explanation are not very valuable. This code doesn't really even answer the question

Comment: My apologizes! I was airheaded and excited that I got it done with a tiny function. I will give more detail!